# How to specify a timeout when streaming rows into BigQuery?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

Basically I want to stream some non-critical data into BigQuery during a very critical part of a system.

I want to specify a max timeout of about 2 seconds because I don't want to be blocking the process too long if there are any connectivity issues, or if BigQuery is not available (which has happened before, although I don't expect it to happen often).

I'm using the `google/cloud` library to connect to BigQuery, and am basically using the code found here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

````
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

/**
 * Stream a row of data into your BigQuery table
 * Example:
 * ```
 * $data = [
 *     "field1" => "value1",
 *     "field2" => "value2",
 * ];
 * stream_row($projectId, $datasetId, $tableId, $data);
 * ```.
 *
 * @param string $projectId The Google project ID.
 * @param string $datasetId The BigQuery dataset ID.
 * @param string $tableId   The BigQuery table ID.
 * @param string $data      An associative array representing a row of data.
 * @param string $insertId  An optional unique ID to guarantee data consistency.
 */
function stream_row($projectId, $datasetId, $tableId, $data, $insertId = null)
{
    // instantiate the bigquery table service
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'projectId' => $projectId,
    ]);
    $dataset = $bigQuery->dataset($datasetId);
    $table = $dataset->table($tableId);

    $insertResponse = $table->insertRows([
        ['insertId' => $insertId, 'data' => $data],
        // additional rows can go here
    ]);
    if ($insertResponse->isSuccessful()) {
        print('Data streamed into BigQuery successfully' . PHP_EOL);
    } else {
        foreach ($insertResponse->failedRows() as $row) {
            foreach ($row['errors'] as $error) {
                printf('%s: %s' . PHP_EOL, $error['reason'], $error['message']);
            }
        }
    }
}
````

I believe their library uses Guzzle as a http client, but I don't know how to pass along that I want a timeout to occur after a set time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best recommendation I can give you: Don't stream directly to BigQuery from a process you don't want to block. Set up a service in the middle that can take care of handling timeouts and retries, while leaving your main process unblocked.

Some options are:

- [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/)
- [Fluentd](https://github.com/kaizenplatform/fluent-plugin-bigquery)
- [kikinteractive/go-bqstreamer](https://github.com/kikinteractive/go-bqstreamer)

You can see some architectural reasons for this on the stories Shine posted 3 years ago: https://shinesolutions.com/2014/08/25/put-on-your-streaming-shoes/ and https://shinesolutions.com/2014/12/19/license-to-queue/.

Comment: ..and then the next generation solution (using proper queues): https://shinesolutions.com/2014/12/19/license-to-queue/

Comment: I was afraid this was going to be the case, both of your links are very useful, though, so thanks for that! Seeing as this doesn't technically answer my question of "How to specify a timeout when streaming rows into BigQuery?" and this answer doesn't explicitly state that it's impossible, should I be marking this answer as accepted? I'm unsure of the rules on this

Comment: The most important part of the question for me is when it states "[because] I don't want to be blocking the process too long if there are any connectivity issues". Then then right answer is "don't even try - if not blocking is important, then do this instead".

Answer (score 1):

It was a little unclear to me at first, but you can just pass along options to the Guzzle http handler using the `httpOptions` option, including a timeout.

In the code snippet above, you would modify the `$table->insertRows()` statement as such:

```
$insertResponse = $table->insertRows([
    ['insertId' => $insertId, 'data' => $data],
    // additional rows can go here
], ['httpOptions' => ['timeout' => $timeoutInSeconds]]);
```

In there you can specify any request options as listed here: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

Nevertheless, Felipe's answer is probably still the better advice.